# OAuth Client ID

Tags: oauth

OAuth 2.0 client ID in Android cannot be replaced with SHA-1. After deletion, when trying to recreate the credentials, it prompts that they have already been used. Please help me with this issue. Thank you.

Create new credentials or modify the sha1 of the current credentials

Comment: Currently, it's hard to help you as we have too little detail. Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question that is more likely to be resolved by the SO community.